# Extract data from Http rest api, How to configure http request header for cookie authentication

Tags: restful-authentication, azure-data-factory

I need to extract data from Http web API. However it requires cookie authentication. I can get the cookie information when I inspect the chrome browser. But I don't know how to configure the headers and authentication type on Azure Data Factory V2. Can you please provide some details ? (for the token based authentication, I have successfully extracted the data. But cookie one, I don't know how to do it)

Comment: hi,if my answer is beneficial for you,would you please accept it for answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#supported-capabilities), ADF REST Linked Service only supports below authentications:

- Anonymous,
- Basic,
- AAD service principal,
- managed identities for Azure resources.

[image]

cookie authentication is not supported by ADF.

Comment: Thank you. is there any plan MS will support this?

Comment: @Edison ADF is azure cloud service,it only could be accessed with rest api ,powershell,sdk etc. So,i'm afraid it won't support cookie auth. However, you also could contact with azure team to ask some official answer. If any progress,you could post here for others' references on the forum. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only way Id found to do such thing is to create an Azure Function and do the API call within using HttpClient, and then just add the cookie to the request object.

You will need to optimize how the call to your api is made and also what type of data you will return from the Azure Function Activity.